# Premiere encode in h264 using "ultrafast" preset

Tags: ffmpeg, premiere, h.264

Often I use Premiere to transcode or export media where the final size isn't the main problem.

I'm used to the ultrafast preset from ffmpeg, what I wonder is.. it is possible to pick the same options that I generally use: QuickTime as container and H.264 but set also the ultrafast option ?

My pc is very slow and this would be a lifesaver for encoding times.

Answer (score 1):

Not out-of-the-box as far as I'm aware. Those presets are specific to the x26* encoders. Premiere bundles Mainconcept's H.264 encoder. You can try third party plugins which allow one to use x264 from within Premiere:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/x264vfw/

http://www.x264pro.com/

Comment: Thanks, it seems it costs a lot however, 250 $, I'm looking for a free solution, and sourceforge one linked show viruses on virustotal check.

Comment: Many people use the SF one. It shows clean at https://www.virustotal.com/en/url/8850e7699a7356d930a7fb2683cf4f70dcd69da3090fd70e70163dcf062dc66e/analysis/1502294490/

Comment: The correct scan of that file is done via file upload and is this one: https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/d7f174d122bfe6b16b6479fc8c480893c0b5252865cdfab3a81fcc15dc877e44/analysis/

Comment: That's 3/64 and 2 of those are heuristic matches, not positive IDs. Test using your local A/V but I doubt it's a problem.